# Sequence of div change layout with same CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A user is creating 2 div's as follows:-

```
<div id="btn_3" class="tmpclass ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 481px;"> content </div>
<div id="field_1" class="tmpclass ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="position: relative; left: 2px; top: 1px;">   Some content </div>
```

Now layout looks like this:-

## [Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/9wf8t93g/)

If i change the sequence of div then it changes the complete layout.
After changing sequence new layout looks like this:-

## [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/ntb9hxz9/)

I am creating second layout using JQuery, So any div can come first. So i want second layout as first even if i change sequence.

Note:- I am adding layout and showing layout using JQuery (prepend method). And it has lots of code with DB access, That's why I am giving you html code to explain what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where each div should be displayed, you have some predefined rules/logic. Therefore, you can write a small method which puts html in a necessary (predefined) place.

The problem is that you prepend what you do not want to prepend and then you are trying to override it.

If you need a lot of flexibility, please describe your project / use cases / types of divs. I am able to help you with snippets and relevant links.